# ¿Cómo formatear con Subíndices para cifras de un máximo de trillones con Regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.9

Estoy manejando cifras muy grandes con mogollón de decimales y, por defecto sale algo como esto:
`43567343880606349864723.22252246987937919546395`, así para saber a simple vista si la cifra no pasa de los miles de billones o pasa a los trillones, te puedes quedar bizco de por vida. Lo mejor es convertir la puntuación numérica, primero a la española con el punto de millar y la coma decimal:

```
import decimal
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

Cifra = decimal.Decimal("43567343880606349864723.22252246987937919546395")
Cifra2 = '{0:n}'.format(Cifra)
print(Cifra2)

>> 43.567.343.880.606.349.864.723,22252246987937919546395
```

Ahora ya se ve un poco más arreglado, pero todavía tengo que contar a mano cuántos puntos de millar; millones, miles de millones, billones, miles de billones, puff una locura....

Así que he preparado una rutina para añadir los subíndices correspondientes hasta una cifra máxima de miles de trillones. La rutina, que tiene alrededor de 30 líneas, funciona perfectamente, pero creo que la mejor forma sería mediante una Expresión Regular (o Regex), resultaría en pocas líneas, y lo más importante sería mucho más rápida. He trabajado un poco con ellas y por eso sé que son bastante complicadas, en concreto lo que quiero conseguir con los subíndices, se requeriría de algún experto en el tema, y por eso ofreceré una buena recompensa (si puedo) para la solución.

Esta es mi rutina provisional por si la necesitáis:

```
""" Subíndices para cifras de un máximo de trillones """

import re
import locale
import time
import decimal
import random
from colorama import Fore

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
decimal.getcontext().prec = 40

p = re.compile('[.]')

def Subindice(Cif):
    Cifra = '{0:n}'.format(Cif)
    if Cif < 1000000:
        return Cifra
    
    iterator = p.finditer(Cifra)
    puntos = []

    for punto in iterator:
        puntos.append(punto.span()[0])
        
    puntos = list(reversed(puntos))
    L = len(puntos)
    i = 1
    punto = puntos[i]
    Cifra = Cifra[:punto] + "₁" + Cifra[punto+1:]
    i += 2
    if i >= L:
        return Cifra
    else:
        punto = puntos[i]
        Cifra = Cifra[:punto] + "₂" + Cifra[punto+1:] 
        i += 2
        if i >= L:
            return Cifra
        else:
            punto = puntos[i]
            Cifra = Cifra[:punto] + "₃" + Cifra[punto+1:] 
            return Cifra

ahora = time.time()
desde = 1000000000000000000 # Desde 1 trillón
hasta = 999999999999999999999999 # Hasta 999.999 trillones
for c in range(100000):
    nAleatorio1 = str(random.randint(desde, hasta))
    nAleatorio2 = random.random()
    nConvert1 = decimal.Decimal(nAleatorio1)
    nConvert2 = decimal.Decimal.from_float(nAleatorio2)
    nConvert = nConvert1 + nConvert2
    print('{0:n}'.format(c), Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX, Subindice(nConvert), Fore.RESET)

print("Tiempo TOTAL:", time.time() - ahora, "segundos")
```

[image: Una captura del final del resultado]

[image: Prueba desde el cmd, mejor que desde Vs Code]

Puesto que las regex no pueden modificar las subcadenas encontradas, en la misma expresión, es decir, hay que modificarlas mediante programación, he modificado un poco mi rutina para que la podáis probar en vuestros equipos y comparar velocidad. Sustituir vuestra función por la mía, sin tocar nada más, para que la comparativa sea lo más exacta posible. Adjunto una captura del final de la prueba, con mi viejo procesador Quad Core, para 100.000 cifras 80 segundos.
Entonces, daré la recompensa a la rutina más rápida, incluida la mía para comparar. Espero que se la lleve alguien y no se desperdicie.

Comment: ¿Quieres hacer una funcion con una regex para ayudarte a organizar el numero de forma mas legible como tu funcion `Subindice`?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es saber el tamaño de un número tan "grande", te recomiendo cambiar a notación exponencial. Así sabrías el número de cifras...
Por ejemplo tu numero daría num*10^23. no tiene que ser 10, puede ser otra base, por ejemplo base 1000: num2*43*1000^7. Donde 7 es el número de tripletas ( 43, tripleta, tripleta, tripleta,...) 2 tripletas son un millón, 4 son 1 billlón 5 son trillon, 6 son cuatrillón... y así.

Comment: Linea 12, `Cifra = '{0:n}'.format(Cif)` CIf is not defined. ¿Por que Cif?

Comment: Uy que fallo, ya lo modifiqué, sorry. Cif es el argumento que se le pasa a la función, es la cifra sin formatear.

Comment: @FrankMascarell tu código sera mas rápido si corres solamente una vez `p = re.compile('[.]')`, saca esa linea y ponla fuera de la función, no tiene sentido compilar el mismo objeto regex cien mil veces.

Comment: Cierto, aunque la diferencia es poca. He añadido otra captura con dos pruebas desde el cmd, más rápido que desde Vs Code. La imagen de la izquierda es con la línea modificada, y la de la derecha con p = re.compile('[.]') dentro de la función. El colorama no funciona aquí.

Comment: Luego de leer todos tus comentarios te recomendaria un par de cosas... Revisa que hacen las regex... en el 99% de los casos, relentizan el codigo de cualquier cosa. El programa tiene que armar un arbol de expressiones y buscar una a una sobre una cadena las coincidencias. Luego, el codigo lo tenes que probar vos. Esto no es un concurso de popularidad, es una pagina de preguntas y respuestas. Se te dieron respuestas, vos probas y decidis si funcionan o no. Pedir que las prueben, no es agradable. y luego menos lineas no significa menos codigo. (sigue)

Comment: python es un lenguaje interpretado, con lo cual, salvo que hayas leido la especificacion del lenguaje, no sabes cuantas lineas van a ser ejecutadas en C de lo que escribiste en python. Muchas veces, mas codigo y menos magia funcionan mejor que menos codigo magico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero que hice fue identificar un patrón donde cuentas los puntos de mil y cada dos puntos de mil reemplazas ese punto por un subíndice que te indica si es millón, billón, trillon, etc. Buscamos si **la posición de el punto de mil es par*** y si lo es entonces ***la posición de el punto de mil la dividimos en dos*** y entonces reemplazamos ese punto de mil por el subíndice correspondiente de esta manera:

```
----------132.155.444.111.333.198.772.773.457,3333312-----------
             |                       |   |
         '8' es par                  |   |
       8/2=4 así que                 | '1'no 
    132₄155.444₃111.333...           | es par
                                     |
                                     |
                                '2' es par, lo
                            reemplazamos por 2/2=1
                          así que ...777₁773.457,3333...
```

No use regex para resolverlo pues creo que tu problema no se resuelve con regex si no que lo resuelve el patrón de formato implementado con pura programación.
Teniendo en cuenta que ya tienes un texto formateado con puntos de mil y coma, entonces lo implemente de esta manera y la función principal solo me tomo 17 lineas(contando 4 lineas de comentarios), pero si lo implementas te puede tomar menos pues soy nuevo en python. Probé varios números y la función los recibe muy bien:

```py
CifraCienmil="922.677,3333"
CifraMillon="123.932.832,9321312312"
CifraBillon="77.793.321.422.231,32"
CifraTrillon="7.713.322.333.944.355.777,1"
CifraCuatrillon="879.282.719.333.678.555.665.432.543,993"
CifraQuintillon="442.221.233.111.198.575.722.117.222.188.987,21"

SubIndices=(".", "₁", "₂", "₃", "₄", "₅", "₆", "₇", "₈", "₉")

def obtenerCifraConSubindices(cifra):
    # Obtenemos la cantidad de puntos de la cifra dada
    cantidadPuntosPorCifra=int(0)
    for i in cifra:
        if (i == '.'):
            cantidadPuntosPorCifra+=1
    nuevaCifra=""
    """ Cada dos puntos de mil, remplazamos el punto por el subindice correspondiente 
    de manera que si tenemos 'n' puntos por cifra, 'n' sera divido en 2 y si 'n' es par 
    entonces tendremos el primer subindice """
    while(cantidadPuntosPorCifra > 0):
        for i in cifra:
            if (i == '.'):
                if (cantidadPuntosPorCifra%2 == 0):
                    i=SubIndices[int(cantidadPuntosPorCifra/2)]
                cantidadPuntosPorCifra-=1
            nuevaCifra+=i
    print(nuevaCifra + "\n")        

obtenerCifraConSubindices(CifraCienmil)
obtenerCifraConSubindices(CifraMillon)
obtenerCifraConSubindices(CifraBillon)
obtenerCifraConSubindices(CifraTrillon)
obtenerCifraConSubindices(CifraCuatrillon)
obtenerCifraConSubindices(CifraQuintillon)

#Output:
922.677,3333

123₁932.832,9321312312

77₂793.321₁422.231,32

7₃713.322₂333.944₁355.777,1

879₄282.719₃333.678₂555.665₁432.543,993

442₅221.233₄111.198₃575.722₂117.222₁188.987,21
```

No había probado python pero tu pregunta me motivo ya que me gustan mucho las regex, así que me vi en la tarea de tratar hacerlo con una expresión regular pero me encuentro con un obstáculo y es que una regex no te dice cuantos puntos tiene una cifra, pues eso es trabajo de la programación, veo mas a las regex como herramienta de extraer texto dado un determinado formato y no para introducir al texto uno. Aun asi espero que me sorprendan y resuelvan este ejercicio con regex.

Comment: Es otra alternativa buena mediante programación, pero imagina que la rutina tiene que analizar miles o millones de cifras; la velocidad es importante, por eso quiero hacerlo con regex. En teoría, con regex  podemos crear grupos de subcadenas, para después poder cambiarlos a nuestro gusto. Pero es un desafío incluso para un experto. ¿Es posible? No lo sé.

Comment: @FrankMascarell, hice un script generando **cien mil** números aleatorios de entre 1 millón hasta decillones y los envié hacia un archivo, leí el archivo con la versión del script de la respuesta en un i3 de quinta generación, 4 de ram que apenas llega a los 2ghz y el resultado de tiempo fue: `./cifra.py  2,68s user 0,37s system 86% cpu 3,536`, 2.68 segundos para 100mil lineas de cifras reemplazadas todas correctamente, ¿te parece eso poco potente?

Comment: AgileSoul, había planteado el problema para solucionarlo con Regex (si se puede), porque programáticamente hay muchas maneras de hacerlo. No he llegado a probar velocidades con mi script, pero ya que te has puesto con tu script, ¿Qué tal si comparas velocidades en tu equipo con el script de Candid Moe y el mío, solo por curiosidad? Pero no creo que halla una diferencia importante entre nuestros scripts; pero sí la habría con una Regex. En cualquier caso, la recompensa que pondré en 15 horas, sólo será para una respuesta con Regex que funcione 100%.

Comment: SI se puede hacer con regex, yo lo hice pero me va 0.5s mas lento, no es muy bueno la lógica que hice, si lo logro hacer con otra lógica que supere la velocidad de esta respuesta pues la pondré. Prueba tu mismo la velocidad de tu script con el comando: ``time python3 [nombre.py]`` y me cuentas

Comment: Pues, si has conseguido hacer una regex que funcione bien (aunque funcione más lenta), FELICIDADES, has dado un gran paso. No quiero ni imaginarme el churro de regex que te habrá salido O.O Pero eso es lo de menos, si mejora el rendimiento.

Answer (score 5):

Esta función recibe un valor numérico y lo retorna en formato "99.999.999,9999" (largo variable):

```
indices=("", "₁", "₂", "₃", "₄", "₅", "₆", "₇", "₈", "₉")

def cobol_pic(valor):
    ent, dec = str(f"{valor}.").split('.', 1)
    dec = f",{dec[:-1]}" if len(dec) > 1 else ""
    digitos = len(ent)
    primer_grupo = digitos % 3

    if primer_grupo:
        resultado = f"{ent[:primer_grupo]}"
        ent = ent[primer_grupo:]
    else:
        resultado = ''

    grupos = [resultado, *[ent[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(ent), 3)]]
    salida = [f"{grupo}{marca}" for grupo, marca in zip(grupos[::-1], indices )]

    return ''.join(salida[::-1]) + dec
```

Primero convertimos el valor (12345678.901234) a string y lo separamos en parte entera y decimal usando `split('.')`:

```
ent, dec = str(f"{valor}.").split('.', 1) => "12345678", "901234"
```

Nota: Agregamos un "." al final del valor recibido en caso de que no traiga parte decimal. Eso agrega un carácter adicional que eliminaremos a continuación:

```
dec = f",{dec[:-1]}" if len(dec) > 1 else ""
```

Con eso dejamos formateada la parte decimal.

Nos interesa saber la cantidad de dígitos de la parte entera. El resto de la división por 3 nos dirá cuantos dígitos hay en el primer grupo de la izquierda:

```
digitos = len(ent)
primer_grupo = digitos % 3 => 8 % 3 -> 2
```

El valor `primer_grupo` nos dice si hay o no un grupo de una o dos cifras al comienzo. En tal caso, las sacamos aparte y cortamos la parte entera a un múltiplo de 3:

```
if primer_grupo:
    resultado = f"{ent[:primer_grupo]}" => "12"
    ent = ent[primer_grupo:] => "345678"
else:
    resultado = ""
```

Ahora voy a trozar la parte entera restante en pedazos de tres digitos:

```
[ent[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(ent), 3)] => ['345', '678']
```

y luego armo una lista agregando el primer grupo de digitos:

```
[resultado, *[ent[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(ent), 3)]] => ['12', '345', '678']
```

El operador estrella (`*`) delante de la compresión de lista transforma la lista en una serie de valores escalares.

A continuación genero una lista de valores editados, recorriendo la parte entera por grupos de derecha a izquierda (uso `[::-1]`). Uso `zip` para iterar en dos listas a la vez, uniendo con *f-string* el grupo de digitos con su respectivo indice.

```
salida = [f"{grupo}{marca}" for grupo, marca in zip(grupos[::-1], indices )] => ['678', '345₁', '12₂']
```

Sólo me queda invertir la lista, hacer un `join`, agregar la parte decimal y retornar

```
return ''.join(salida[::-1]) + dec3)]]) => 12₂345₁678,90123
```

#### Demo

```
import decimal

indices=("", "₁", "₂", "₃", "₄", "₅", "₆", "₇", "₈", "₉")

def cobol_pic(valor):
    ent, dec = str(f"{valor}.").split('.', 1)
    dec = f",{dec[:-1]}" if len(dec) > 1 else ""
    digitos = len(ent)
    primer_grupo = digitos % 3

    if primer_grupo:
        resultado = f"{ent[:primer_grupo]}"
        ent = ent[primer_grupo:]
    else:
        resultado = ''

    grupos = [resultado, *[ent[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(ent), 3)]]
    salida = [f"{grupo}{marca}" for grupo, marca in zip(grupos[::-1], indices )]

    return ''.join(salida[::-1]) + dec


tests = [
    decimal.Decimal("12345678.90123"),
    decimal.Decimal("0"),
    decimal.Decimal("-1"),
    decimal.Decimal("0."),
    decimal.Decimal("0.0"),
    decimal.Decimal("1.0"),
    decimal.Decimal("-1.12"),
    decimal.Decimal("43567343880606349864723.22252246987937919546395")
    ]

for test in tests:
    print(test, "->", cobol_pic(test))
```

produce:

```
12345678.90123 -> 12₂345₁678,90123
0 -> 0
-1 -> -1
0 -> 0
0.0 -> 0,0
1.0 -> 1,0
-1.12 -> -1,12
43567343880606349864723.22252246987937919546395 -> 43₇567₆343₅880₄606₃349₂864₁723,22252246987937919546395

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Candid Moe, tú función también es buena para solucionar el problema, aunque siguen siendo varias líneas de programación, que en apariencia son menos, pero tienes un estilo muy peculiar en cuanto a comprimir varias instrucciones en una misma línea, con lo cual, al ejecutarse todas ellas serán igual de rápidas que si las pusieras en diferentes líneas con una lectura más amena. Pero bueno, cada uno se adapta a la mejor manera que cree conveniente.  Gracias por tu ayuda, pero sigo necesitando una regex. A ver si algún experto en jeroglíficos egipcios, aparece por aquí y se tira al rollo  ;)

Comment: @FrankMascarell. Haz tú las pruebas.

Comment: Lo intenté con dos de los códigos aquí expuestos y no me funcionaron, me dio errores. Por eso es mejor con un código común para todos y ajustéis vosotros mismos, vuestras rutinas.

Comment: @CandidMoe Pareciera un jefe (quien hizo la pregunta) dando ordenes y poniendo a trabajar por 100 puntos, 100 puntos que no valen ni 1 centavo literalmente, ni 1 segundo del salario minimo de una persona. Ojalá FrankMascarell fuese más agradecido con personas que ofrecen su tiempo de forma voluntaria para resolver preguntas de otras personas.

Comment: @AlfredoMaussa, he agradecido a todos los usuarios su colaboración, por escrito. A mi me parece que si un usuario tiene 500 y pico puntos, y ofrece 100, es la quinta parte de lo que tiene, y para mí es más que suficiente para 4 líneas de código sencillas. Yo he planteado la pregunta y por consiguiente decido cómo quiero la respuesta. Yo no te he dado ninguna orden que estés obligado a seguir. Es muy fácil, si no te gusta el hilo, no sigas. Los comentarios negativos no son bienvenidos. Estamos para divertirnos, mientras programamos. o eso se pretende :D

Answer (score 4):

##### Explicación:

La idea básica es tomar el índice de la coincidencia (*match*) literal de`.` y dividirlo por 3 (4 si incluye el punto, `//` para división entera).

Regex, `re.sub` permite realizar un callback para cada coincidencia. Siendo así se utiliza `re.MatchObject.end()` [[Documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.end)] para obtener el indice de izquierda a derecha.

El valor del indice deberá ser desde derecha a izquierda por lo que se resta un offset:numero de caracteres hasta la coma decimal. Luego se inverte (-1) al restar.

### Solución con puntos de separación en la entrada

```py
# Importar Regex
import re
# Para mapear a subindices
mapSubIndex=str.maketrans("1234567890", "\u2081\u2082\u2083\u2084\u2085\u2086\u2087\u2088\u2089\u2080")
# Cifra de entrada
# Cifra = "879.282.719.333.678.555.665.432.543.678.555.665.432.543,22252246987937919546395"
Cifra = "879.282.719.333.678.555.665.432.543.678.555.665.432.543"
# Número de caracteres hasta la coma decimal
offset=re.search(',',Cifra).end() if re.search(',',Cifra) else len(Cifra)+1
# Regex solución
re.sub('[.]',lambda m: f'{(offset-m.end())//4}'.translate(mapSubIndex),Cifra)
```

- Intento fallido para obtener indice `pattern.groupindex` [groupindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856238/how-to-get-group-name-of-match-regular-expression-in-python)
- Intenté escribir `f'\u208{numero}'` pero obtuve: [how to fix - error: bad escape \u at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54330673/how-to-fix-error-bad-escape-u-at-position-0), al final usé [Cómo mapear caracteres (recursos)]

###### Salidas

Para entrada `"879.282.719.333.678.555.665.432.543.678.555.665.432.543"`

```
"879₁₃282₁₂719₁₁333₁₀678₉555₈665₇432₆543₅678₄555₃665₂432₁543"
```

Para entrada `"879.282.719.333.678.555.665.432.543.678.555.665.432.543,22252246987937919546395"`

```
"879₁₃282₁₂719₁₁333₁₀678₉555₈665₇432₆543₅678₄555₃665₂432₁543,22252246987937919546395"
```

##### Solución sin puntos de separación en la entrada

```py
Cifra = "87922833233678555665432367855566543253,22252246987937919546395"

padding=3-len(Cifra.split(',')[0]) % 3
offset=len(Cifra.split(',')[0])+padding+1
result=re.sub('(\d{3}),?',lambda m: m.group(1)+f'{(offset-m.end())//3}'.translate(mapSubIndex),padding*'0'+Cifra)
```

###### Salida

`'087₁₂922₁₁833₁₀233₉678₈555₇665₆432₅367₄855₃566₂543₁253₀222-₁522-₂469-₃879-₄379-₅195-₆463-₇95'`

La salida queda con ceros a la izquierda, para borrar usar:
`result[5 if padding==3 else padding:]`

Recursos:

- [Cómo escribir subíndices en python @Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391892/printing-subscript-in-python)
- [Cómo mapear caracteres](https://codeigo.com/python/printing-subscript-and-superscript)

Comment: Sigue siendo mediante programación; No hay una única regex. Demasiadas instrucciones en la última línea y por consiguiente demasiado confusa (aunque no importa). Gracias por el aporte Alfredo Maussa.

Answer (score 4):

Bueno aquí te traigo la forma en que lo hice, creo que es muy simplificada.
Primero he creado la expresión regular de esta forma:

```py
regex = re.compile("\d{3}\.\d{3}")
```

Esta expresión regular cumplirá con aquellos string que tengan 3 cifras un punto y 3 cifras más, lo que vendría a considerarse un millón.

Luego usaremos el método `findall` para obtener todas las coincidencias en forma de lista, pero este método se lo aplicaremos al string invertido, esto lo hacemos con la sintaxis de slice (`[inicio:fin:paso]`) y luego obtendremos el índice de la parte que no cumple con el millón.

```py
millons = regex.findall(cifra[::-1])
ultimo = cifra.index(millons[-1][::-1])
```

Con esto ya tenemos casi todo, solo faltaría iterar en la variable `millons` para regresar las cifras a su orden original y colocar los subíndices. Para los subíndices utilizaremos el método `.maketrans` para crear los subíndices y luego usaremos `.translate` para reemplazar los números normales por subíndices

```py
#creamos el diccionario de subíndices
SUB = str.maketrans("0123456789", "₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉")

#reordenamos las cifras y colocamos los subíndices
millons = [f'{str(millons.index(cifra)+1).translate(SUB)}{cifra[::-1]}' for cifra in millons[::-1]]
```

Finalmente solo nos quedaría imprimir la lista `millons` junto a la primera parte del string.

```py
print(f"{cifra[:ultimo]}{''.join(millons)}{decimal}")
```

Todo esto lo he llevado a una función donde he añadido algunos `if`s para evitar errores o avisar de sintaxis inválida.

```py
impor re

def subindice(cifra):
    if "." in cifra and "," in cifra and cifra.index(",")< cifra.index("."): raise ValueError("sintaxis invalida")
    try:
        if "." not in cifra: return float(cifra)
        
        regex = re.compile("\d{3}\.\d{3}")
        millons = regex.findall(cifra[::-1])
        ultimo = cifra.index(millons[-1][::-1]) 

        SUB = str.maketrans("0123456789", "₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉")
        
        millons = [f'{str(millons.index(cifra)+1).translate(SUB)}{cifra[::-1]}' for cifra in millons[::-1]]

        decimal = ""
        if "," in cifra: #si existe parte decimal
            decimal = cifra[cifra.index(","):]
        return f"{cifra[:ultimo]}{''.join(millons)}{decimal}"
    except:
        return cifra
```

En caso se introduzca un string así `1,000.000` dará error, pues esta no es la sintaxis correcta de un número. En caso falle algo del código, simplemente retornará el string original.

**Probamos**
Lo siento, me copie de los datos de prueba de @AgileSoul

```py
CifraCienmil="922.677,3333"
CifraMillon="123.932.832,9321312312"
CifraBillon="77.793.321.422.231,32"
CifraTrillon="7.713.322.333.944.355.777,1"
CifraCuatrillon="879.282.719.333.678.555.665.432.543,993"
CifraQuintillon="442.221.233.111.198.575.722.117.222.188.987,21"

print(subindice(CifraCienmil))
print(subindice(CifraMillon))
print(subindice(CifraBillon))
print(subindice(CifraTrillon))
print(subindice(CifraCuatrillon))
print(subindice(CifraQuintillon))
print(subindice("1.00.0000"))
```

**Salida**

```
₁922.677,3333
123.₁932.832,9321312312
77.₂793.321₁422.231,32
7.₃713.322₂333.944₁355.777,1
879.₄282.719₃333.678₂555.665₁432.543,993
442.₅221.233₄111.198₃575.722₂117.222₁188.987,21
1.00.0000
```

El código *real* es bastante reducido, puedes quitar los `if`s y quedarte solo con el `try/except` pero para mejorar la experiencia de usuario los he añadido.

El único *error* que podría considerarse que hay es al momento de trabajar con miles, pues en el primer caso de `922.677,3333` se nos muestra el subíndice 1 indicando que desde ahí comenzaría los millones (que puede ser evitado con `if len(cifra.split("."))<3: return cifra`). Otro pequeño detalle es el punto `.`, por ejemplo, `123.₁932....`, esto se podría eliminar si se hace `f"f{cifra[:ultimo-1]}{''.join(millons)}{decimal}"`, pero el problema de esto es que  al trabajar con miles (primer caso), el string se duplica, dado que `ultimo` contendría el valor `0` y si le restamos 1 queda `-1` y al hacer `cifra[:ultimo-1]` se coge el string completo. Fuera de estos pequeños detalles que pueden ser arreglados con un `if` considero que el programa funciona bastante bien.

Comment: Chistian, al igual que le respondí a ChemaCortes, y gracias por la aportación.

Comment: 14 líneas es bastante simplificado, lo puedes simplificar más pero no creo que sea muy legible, si buscas todo resumido en 3 líneas dudo que encuentres algo así hecho desde 0. Igual muchas gracias a ti, me has puesto ha pensar un buen rato :D

Comment: Y ya lo has probado tu?

Comment: Lo intenté con dos de los códigos aquí expuestos y no me funcionaron, me dio errores. Por eso es mejor con un código común para todos y ajustéis vosotros mismos, vuestras rutinas. Yo lo probaré, si alguien pone una rutina más rápida.

Comment: En ese caso deberías de comentárselo a los usuario que publicaron la respuesta, si no puedes ejecutarlo entonces la respuesta no sirve y es necesario hacérselo saber . Creo que aún no entiendes muy bien como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Lo he comentado en varios sitios que los códigos no me funcionan a mi, pero eso no importa; lo que importa es que algún usuario me diga que su rutina es más rápida y entonces si que intentaré probarlo.

Comment: He leido los comentarios de todas las respuestas y en ninguna has dicho que el código proporcionado no te funciona. Primero debes probarlo tu. ¿Si no te funciona como quieres aceptar la respuesta?

Comment: Si lo dije, pero repito NO IMPORTA. La respuesta válida será el código más rápido. Y todavía ningún usuario me ha demostrado o dicho que su código es X segundos más rápido, con respecto al mío. Cuando alguien lo haga, entonces probaré la rutina. Pero insisto, la rutina tiene que tener mi código tal cual, excepto vuestra función, así medimos mejor las velocidades.

Comment: Tienes una mala concepción del sitio, por cierto la mía demora `Tiempo TOTAL: 0.4264981746673584 segundos`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128902/discussion-between-christian-and-frank-mascarell).

Comment: ¿Porqué tengo una mala concepción del sitio? Por Favor, el tiempo con respecto a la mía en tu equipo y, si es más rápida la pruebo en el mío.

Answer (score 3):

Voy a insistir con una solución que use *regex*. La idea es separar las dos partes del número, parte entera y decimal, y dividir en bloques de tres la parte entera para ir intercalando los subíndices. El problema con las expresiones regulares es lo que cuesta entender lo que están haciendo.

Para separar las dos partes podemos emplear una expresión regular así:

```regex
"(\d+)(\.(\d+)?)?"
```

Las dos partes están separadas por el punto, que es necesiario *escapar* de este modo `\.`. La parte entera se obtiene con el primer `(\d+)` y la parte decimal con el segundo. Como la parte decimal puede no estar presente se pone un `?` detrás. Lo mismo pasa con el bloque *"punto + parte decimal"*, contemplando la opción de que tengamos sólo el punto sin ningún decimal (eg: `12.`).

Pero la parte entera queremos dividirla en bloques de tres dígitos para poder intercalar los subíndices. La mejor forma es dividirla en dos, con un bloque que tenga un número de digitos que sea múltiplo de tres y otro residual:

```regex
"(\d*?)((\d{3})*)(\.(\d+)?)?"
```

Para ver como funciona, veamos un ejemplo:

```py
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile("(\d*?)((\d{3})*)(\.(\d+)?)?")
>>> num = "43567343880606349864723.22252246987937919546395"
>>> m = pat.fullmatch(num)
>>> m.groups()
('43', '567343880606349864723', '723', '.22252246987937919546395', '22252246987937919546395')
```

Hemos obtenido 5 grupos. El segundo grupo, `'567343880606349864723'`, es un grupo de 21 dígitos (7 tríos), quedando el `43` suelto.

De los 5 grupos en realidad sólo nos interesan tres. Podemos quitar los grupos que no nos interesan con el indicativo `(?: )`:

```regex
"(\d*?)((?:\d{3})*)(?:\.(\d+)?)?"
```

Del ejemplo anterior, el resultado quedaría así:

```py
('43', '567343880606349864723', '22252246987937919546395')
```

Para dividir en tríos el segundo grupo volvemos a aplicar expresiones regulares.

```py
>>> ter = re.compile("\d{3}")
>>> trios = ter.findall(m.group(2))
>>> trios
['567', '343', '880', '606', '349', '864', '723']
```

A este grupo de tríos es al que queremos aplicar subíndices. Lo adecuado es usar la función `zip` con una cadena que nos relacione cada trío con el subíndice adecuado. La cadena de subíndices debe ser de mayor longitud que la lista de tríos para que la función `zip` no nos trunque los tríos. Quedará algo así:

```py
>>> subs = ".₁.₂.₃.₄.₅.₆.₇.₈.₉."
>>> "".join(reversed([sub+trio for sub, trio in zip(subs, reversed(trios))]))
'.567₃343.880₂606.349₁864.723'
```

Combinando todo esto, obtenemos el siguiente código:

```py
import re

subs = ".₁.₂.₃.₄.₅.₆.₇.₈.₉."

pat = re.compile("(\d*?)((?:\d{3})*)(?:\.(\d+)?)?")
ter = re.compile("\d{3}")


def decomp(s):
    primero, bloque, decimales = pat.fullmatch(s).groups()
    trios = ter.findall(bloque)
    if not primero:
        primero, *trios = trios
    return (primero, trios, decimales)

def formato(s):
    primero, trios, decimales = decomp(s)
    pre = reversed([sub+trio for sub, trio in zip(subs,reversed(trios))])
    res = primero + "".join(pre) + f",{decimales}" if decimales else ""
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = "43567343880606349864723.22252246987937919546395"
    print(formato(s))
```

---

**Editado**: como solución más corta, sin expresiones regulares ni *locales*:

```py
subs = ",.₁.₂.₃.₄.₅.₆.₇.₈.₉."


def formato(s: str) -> str:
    digits, *decimals = s.split(".")

    res = []
    for i, c in enumerate(digits[::-1], 1):
        if i % 3 == 1:
            res.append(subs[i // 3])
        res.append(c)

    return "".join(reversed(res)) + (decimals[0] if decimals else "")
```

Comment: ChemaCortes, muy interesante tu resolución, pero sigo viendo muchas líneas de código, además, ¿No sería mejor aprovechar el método "format" para añadir los puntos de millar y la coma decimal (como en mi rutina) ? Es un trabajo que ya está hecho, con una regex, mejor buscar los puntos de millar y sustituirlos.

Comment: @FrankMascarell Ese formateo que usas se apoya en la librería `locale` de ANSI C. Cualquier alteración de la configuración afecta a todo el programa, provocando problemas rendimiento y _core dumps_ ([documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#background-details-hints-tips-and-caveats)). Por otro lado, no se necesita para nada expresiones regulares si solo quieres localizar puntos decimales. En cuanto a líneas de código, se podría reducir a unas pocas líneas, pero perdería legibilidad.

Comment: De todos modos, añado una versión corta que no usa ni expresiones regulares ni _locales_.

Answer (score 3):

Seguramente no entendí el planteo, porque desde mi perspectiva, ¿para qué expresiones regulares? si es por saber en que límites se encuentra:

```
import decimal
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

cantidad={1:"mil",2:"millón",3:"miles de millón",4:"billón",5:"miles de billón",6:"trillón",7:"miles de trillón"}

Cifra = decimal.Decimal("43567343880606349864723.22252246987937919546395")
Cifra2 = '{0:n}'.format(Cifra)
print(Cifra2)

print(cantidad.get(Cifra2.count("."),"superó los miles de trillón"))
```

en base a tu ejemplo y pudiendo variar la defenición de cantidades

Comment: Porque con una regex el código es más limpio, rápido y además se puede "estandarizar" o compartir con los demás más fácilmente, pero sobre todo por velocidad.

Comment: si el resultado obtenido por lo que hice es el buscado, ¿regex es más rápido que lo espuesto?¿limpio?

Comment: @tincopasan sí, yo creo que regex es engañiso, a pesar de que el código se vea más "limpio" las funciones que utiliza por detrás son muchas... Osea que al final no es que tenga mejor rendimiento que incluso 100 lineas de código. Las operaciones que realiza la librería/módulo por detrás también cuestan.